# Simple (?) CSS Animation of Opacity Property

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

Ok, I don't get this. I've done CSS3 animations before, but for some reason simply animating the opacity isn't working for me today. Am I missing something silly?

**CSS:**

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from: { opacity: 0; }
    to: { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from: { opacity: 0; }
    to: { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from: { opacity: 0; }
    to: { opacity: 1; }
}

#foo {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s ease-in alternate infinite;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s ease-in alternate infinite;
    animation: fadein 2s ease-in alternate infinite;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="foo">This is Foo!</div>
```

I've also posted it as a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/NRutman/Lcyvy/

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
-Nate

Comment: read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUsing_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need colons after `from` and `to`:

```
@keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lcyvy/6/

Comment: Ugh...I knew it was going to be something small like that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
@keyframes fadein {
    from: { opacity: 0; }
    to: { opacity: 1; }
}
```

to

```
@keyframes fadein {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcyvy/4/)